# Retrieving data from db.json file and adding it into an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm using ajax and javascript for a game and I created a server using json-server where I keep a db.json file with words that the user can input and become available in the game.

### db.json

This is what the json file looks like

```
{
  "words": [
    {
      "cuvant": "cuvant",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "cuvant": "masina",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "cuvant": "oaie",
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "cuvant": "carte",
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "cuvant": "fmi",
      "id": 5
    },
    {
      "cuvant": "birou",
      "id": 6
    },
    {
      "cuvant": "birou",
      "id": 7
    },
    {
      "cuvant": "canapea",
      "id": 8
    },
    {
      "cuvant": "pasare",
      "id": 9
```

### I managed to get the POST request (adding the words to the db.json) using this:

```
    function addWord() {
  var word = document.getElementById("input-name").value;
  var info = {
    cuvant: word
  }

  $.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost:3000/words',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(info),
    succes: function(info) {
      console.log(info)
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  })
}
```

### This is what I tried for the GET request

But I'm not sure if it's correct.
And I also need a way to get only the **value** hold by the **cuvant** key and add it into an array.

```
window.onload = function() {
  function gett() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/words',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json",
      succes: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },

      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      }
    })

    .done(function(){
      console.log("Over")
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct. It was just missing the "s" on "success":

```
window.onload = function() {
  function gett() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/words',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      }
    })
    .done(function(){
      console.log("Over")
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: how do I make sure this works the way it should? the terminal in VSCode prints this: GET /words 304 4.281 ms - -